# How to disable the access of Hard drive when boot with Ubuntu LIVE USB

Tags: ubuntu-11.04

I am using a Ubuntu LIVE USB to boot my laptop. However, after I enter the system, I am able to see my C: drive.

Question: Is it possible that I can completely block the access of the internal hard drive from accessing through the Ubuntu?

Thank you

Comment: You can dismount the device.  Of course this also means you can mount it.  This of course also would require sudio permissions or if not I am sure it can be configured to be.

Comment: How can I dismount the internal hard drives?

Comment: @qq0987 - Just use `umount` and `mount`.  I would look up the command to understand the required syntax required to use it of course.

Comment: Unmounting does not solve the ops issue

Answer (score 1):

Think this would help

http://www.ehow.com/how_6800496_turn-off-internal-hard-drive.html

1-
Power on your computer and press the "F2" or "Delete" key when you first see text appear on the screen. This will open the BIOS menu. If neither of these keys work, look closely at the text when the computer first starts. It will tell you the keyboard key to press.

2-
Navigate using the arrow keys on your keyboard. Each BIOS is different, so reference the legend located on the screen to assist you in navigation and making changes.

3-
Find a menu labeled "Hardware" or simply browse each one until you see a listing of drives. They are typically labeled by their model number (see Resources).

4-
Highlight the drive using the arrow keys to navigate and press "Enter" to get a listing of options for it. Highlight "Disabled" or "None" using the arrow keys and press "Enter."

5- Navigate to the "Exit" menu and find an option typically labeled "Save settings and exit." Highlight it and press "Enter." You will be asked to confirm your choice; do so. Check the legend of your BIOS as well, as this option may have a shortcut key; a common one is "F10."

Read more : http://www.ehow.com/how_6800496_turn-off-internal-hard-drive.html

Comment: The question asks about disabling only while in the live session.  Access is still desired when booted normally.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to prevent access to a disk, to someone that has physical access to it, is encrypting it.

Depending on what system(s) is installed on the disk you want to protect, the software and the difficulty of encrypting will vary.

Comment: More detail would improve this answer.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: How so? The only way to prevent access to a disk when you have physical access to it, is encrypting it. The OP didn't state what system is on the disk he wants to protect, so, all he asked has been answered

Answer (score 0):

I used a 2019 or 2020 liveboot ISO version of Lubuntu (which is basically Ubuntu) to accomplish this:

1. Press the power botton > BIOS
2. Press F12
3. Select Boot from flash drive
4. Select language English
5. Press F6
6. Enable Expert mode
7. Select Start Lubuntu
8. Wait a few seconds for the cursor to show up above the white text on a black background I guess > press Ctrl+Alt+F2

I then saw:
"Ubuntu 19.04 lubuntu tty2 \ lubuntu login: lubuntu \ Password: [blank] \ Welcome to Ubuntu 19.04 (GNU/Linux 5.0.0-13-generic x86_64) [...] lubuntu@lubuntu:~$ sudo su \ root@lubuntu:/home/lubuntu#"

I could then tell from running `lsblk` that a removable external 5TB hard drive which was plugged in was not mounted. I think that PCmanFM file manager was automounting it based on what I saw from it at Edit > Preferences. By going into tty I prevented the default startup from running (the default startup starts a program which automounts stuff).

(Why might one want to prevent automounting of a drive? For forensics or backups. When you later want to mount the storage device use `mount -o ro,noload /dev/sda1 .`; that way nothing is written to the write-protected hard drive due to mounting it, and now you can copy the data off of that read-only HDD.)

Useful link: https://askubuntu.com/questions/103896/live-cd-asks-for-a-username-and-password
Possibly useful links: https://www.linuxuprising.com/2020/01/how-to-boot-to-console-text-mode-in.html and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tty_(Unix)